# how to limit checkbox selection with angular or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to follow all the examples out there but I am not having any luck. I created a plunker using a jquery validation check. I need to only allow 1 checkbox selection out of the group. 
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WCW6jxEc8HFnB2Qnc6HX?p=preview)

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="form-group fg-line">
    <label for="companies" class="control-label"><b>Role Type</b></label><br /> <br />
 <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="model in userRoles">
      <td>
        <div class="checkbox m-b-15">
          <label>
            <input id="rolebox" class="check" type="checkbox" ng-model="model.RoleId">
            <i class="input-helper"></i>
               {{model.Name}}
         </label>
       </div>
    </td>
 </tr>
   </table>
      </div>    
      <script>
       var checked = [],
          $check = $('.check').change(function () {
            if (this.value == -1 && this.checked) {
                $check.not(this).prop('disabled', true).prop('checked', false);
                checked = [];
            }
            else {
                $check.prop('disabled', false);
                checked.push(this);
                checked = $(checked)
                checked.prop('checked', false).slice(-2).prop('checked', true);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using a radio rather than a check box, as check boxes typically indicate a multi select where as radios are single. Not to derail the question but just a suggestion.

Comment: good point. didnt think about that

Comment: Or use `if ( $(":checkbox:checked").length > 1 ) { // more than one selected }`

Comment: ca you please show in plunker

Comment: And you have no jQuery included?

Comment: my bad, just updated it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to only allow 1 checkbox selection out of the group.

As mentioned in one of the comments to your question, you should really use radio buttons for this purpose as they are meant for this kind of situation. If you had to use checkboxes, you could do the following.

```
$(document).on("change", ".check", function() {
    var $allCheckboxes = $(".check");
    $allCheckboxes.prop("disabled", false);
    this.checked && $allCheckboxes.not(this).prop("disabled", true);
});
```

[**Your updated plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/4EgMV9CfxjS1AyzmyGjv?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

Assign same `name` value to all checkboxes. For example:

```
 <input name="nm" id="rolebox1" class="check" type="checkbox" ng-model="model.RoleId">
 <input name="nm" id="rolebox2" class="check" type="checkbox" ng-model="model.RoleId">
```